# Confused about Netlify deployment settings for my project

Tags: node.js, deployment, mern, netlify, production

I have a small doubt. I built a MERN project that has two folders "backend" and frontend". How can I deploy this on Netlify and ensure that the backend and frontend are integrated when I deploy?

I haven't tried to make any changes in the settings but for default settings, the project is not deployed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.